# Copy and extend global objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

is there a way to copy a global object (Array,String...) and then extend the prototype of the copy without affecting the original one? I've tried with this:

```
var copy=Array;
copy.prototype.test=2;
```

But if i check `Array.prototype.test` it's 2 because the Array object is passed by reference. I want to know if there's a way to make the "copy" variable behave like an array but that can be extended without affecting the original Array object.

Comment: I assume that first line actually reads: `var copy=Array;`

Comment: For creating an Array-like "class" see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/366031/implement-array-like-behavior-in-javascript-without-using-array  
  
It also seems like you don't understand Javascript inheritance. You should Google something like "Javascript prototypal inheritance".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. I have a feeling you might have to write a wrapper class for this. What you're essentially doing with `copy.prototype.test=2` is setting a class prototype which will (of course) be visible for all instances of that class.

Comment: Have you got some example for the wrapper class?

Comment: @mck89: sorry, I hadn't noticed your comment on here. S.O.'s notice feature needs some work, lol. I take it you managed to get a wrapper class sorted?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason the example in http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2006/11/hooray/ doesn't work is because it's an anonymous function. So, instead of the following:

```
// create the constructor
var Array2 = function() {
  // initialise the array
};

// inherit from Array
Array2.prototype = new Array;

// add some sugar
Array2.prototype.each = function(iterator) {
// iterate
};
```

you would want something like this:

```
function Array2() {

}
Array2.prototype = new Array();
```

From my own testing, the `length` property is maintained in IE with this inheritance. Also, anything added to `MyArray.prototype` does not appear to be added to `Array.prototype`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extending the prototype, why don't you simply extend the copy variable. For example, adding a function

```
copy.newFunction = function(pParam1) { 
      alert(pParam1);
};
```

Comment: Because in this way if i create a new instance of copy it won't have the method because it will take only prototype methods. Anyway this doesn't solve the problem because it extends the original Array object too.