# Extending an Array properly, keeping the instance of subclass

Tags: javascript, inheritance, coffeescript, prototypal-inheritance

I've written a class trying to extend the native Javascript `Array` class with a custom class, let's call it `MyClass`. This is basically what it looks like:

```
class MyClass extends Array

  constructor: (obj) -> @push.apply @, obj

  first: -> @slice 0, 1
```

Instantiating the class is no problem. Running this in the console:

```
var myInstance = new MyClass(["1", "2"])
> ["1", "2"]
myInstance instanceof MyClass
> true
myInstance instanceof Array
> true
```

works as exptected.

The problem is that if I run:

```
myInstance.first()
> ["1"] // as expected
myInstance.first() instanceof MyClass
> false // not expected
myInstance.first() instanceof Array
> true
```

the returned value is no longer an instance of MyClass.

I've also tried `@__proto__.first = @first` in the constructor function and `first: -> @slice.call @, 0, 1`. But with no success.

Why doesn't `myInstance.first() instanceof MyClass` return `true`?

Comment: I don't think extending Array will ever work properly (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3261587/479863), why are you trying to do it?

Comment: Basically this is only experimental, I wanted to see if it's possible. Instead of polluting the `Array` class, I wanted to rather augment my own class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why doesn't `myInstance.first() instanceof MyClass` return true?

Because `first` calls `slice`, and `Array.prototype.slice` does always return an `Array`. You will need to overwrite it with a method that wraps it in a `MyClass` again:

```
class MyClass extends Array

  constructor: (obj) -> @push.apply @, obj

  slice: () -> new MyClass super
  splice: () -> new MyClass super
  concat: () -> new MyClass super
  filter: () -> new MyClass super
  map: () -> new MyClass super

  first: -> @slice 0, 1
```

And notice that [subclassing `Array` does not work](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/).

Comment: Thanks! That solves the issue! However regarding memory footprint, wouldn't `new MyClass super` consume a bit more memory? Also, thanks for the article link!

Comment: Sure it will. However, you *want* more than an `Array` :-)

Comment: Yep, I totally get that. My questions should have been phrased like this; is there a way to create a new instance once, instead of each time I use for example `slice()`?

Comment: I don't understand, the purpose of `slice` is to return a different, new instance? Do you want it to mutate your instance?

Comment: I'm out in deep water here, but I though `Array.prototype.slice` only modified the existing instance of an array, rather than creating a new instance. That's why I wondered if that was doable for a subclass of `Array` as well. Maybe I'm just confused :)

Comment: No, it doesn't modify. All the other array methods that do mutate (like `sort`, `push`, `shift`, …) work on `MyClass` instances without problems.