# Array Access of Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, coffeescript

In coffee script i have this little code snippet.

```
class Collection

  construct:(@collection=[])
```

Now i want to access that object as if it was an array but i want to get the collection variable when i do so. In other languages i would implements an ArrayAccess of some type and code the next, current etc methods

```
obj= new Collection([1,2,3])

obj[0] # this should equal 1
```

How can i do this in javascript or coffeescript either will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's impossible. You would need some kind of [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13059975/1048572) for that. There is no "ArrayAccess" declaration feature, as bracket notation is just property access on your `Collection` instance (like `obj["collection"]`).

Instead, you can:

- implement a getter function, like

  ```
  class Collection
    construct:(@collection=[])
    at: (i) ->
      @collection[i]

  obj.at 0 # 1
  ```
- use the `Collection` object itself as a holder of the elements (like e.g. jQuery does it). You loose the native array features, though. You might even [subclass `Array` to some extent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490302/1048572) (`.length` does not update automatically).

  ```
  class Collection
    constructor: (col = []) ->
      @length = 0
      for el in col
        Array::push.call(@, el)

  obj[0] # 1
  ```

Comment: The at is a good idea. maybe coupled with an all for foreach loops.

Comment: @Lpc_dark: `each` please, `all` is a common synonym for [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)