# How to Construct an array by es6 class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I expect that a class return an array when I `new` it

```
class MyArray {
  constructor(){

  }
}

const myArray = new MyArray()
Array.isArray(myArray) // Should be true
```

I used to write it in this way:

```
class MyArray {
  constructor(){
    const arry = new Array()
    return arry
  }
}
```

But when I write in Typescript,the return value `arry` is not the type of MyArray, so it prompt an error.

How to fixed this problem?

Comment: Why do you want to achieve such strange behavior?

Comment: you are looking for collection class

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why should `Array.isArray(myArray)` be `true` when it's obviously a `class` and not an array.

Comment: Possible dup of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261587/subclassing-javascript-arrays-typeerror-array-prototype-tostring-is-not-generi

Comment: I want to customize my array-like data structure

Answer (score 7):

Just extend `Array` and `return true` in the *constructor*

```
class MyArray extends Array{
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
}
```

**Demo**

```js
class MyArray extends Array{
  constructor(){
    super()
  }
}

myArray2 = new MyArray()
console.log(Array.isArray(myArray2));
```