# Angular 8 : TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator

Tags: angular, typescript

When i'am sending `http get` request then i'am getting these error `TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator`,but it works in `Angular 7` not in `Angular 8`.

**My Component file**
From `component.ts` file i have called service `getCodes()`

```
onSubmit(){
 this.service.getCodes('localhost/Aggregator/getCodes').subscribe (result=>{
 }, error =>{
    console.log(error);
 })
}
```

**My Interceptor file**
When i 'am sending request then that time i have passed these header through interceptor

```
@Injectable()
    export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
      sessionParam:any = {
        userParam: {
          'a':66,
          'b':101,
          'c':'0201',
          'd':'Y',
          'e':'Y',
          'h':'2019/02/22',
          'f':'Y',
          'g':12
        }
      }

      intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let headers = new HttpHeaders();
        for (var val in this.sessionParam) {
          Object.keys(this.sessionParam[val]).forEach(key => {
            headers = headers.append(key,this.sessionParam[val][key]);
          });
        }
        request = request.clone({
          headers: headers
        })
        return next.handle(request);
      }
    }
```

**My Service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProvidersService {

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  public getCodes(url, apiParam=null):Observable<any>
  {
    return this.http.get(url, {params: apiParam});
  }
}
```

**I'am getting following error**

```
TypeError: Found non-callable @@iterator
at HttpHeaders.applyUpdate (http.js:301)
at http.js:245
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at HttpHeaders.init (http.js:241)
at HttpHeaders.forEach (http.js:339)
at Observable._subscribe (http.js:1826)
at Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:42)
at Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:28)
at subscribeTo.js:20
at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:7)
```

any solutions ?

Comment: Would recommend looking here for insight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54526625/1284088

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261587/subclassing-javascript-arrays-typeerror-array-prototype-tostring-is-not-generi

Answer (score 26):

This error occurs when you set headers non-string values. In order to solve convert all header values to string.

Answer (score 12):

I have upgraded from A7 to A8 and experienced same issue.

In my case the code was failing on a row where I used *destructuring assignment*:

```
return this.fooPipe.transform(foo, ...args);

-> Error: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

It has helped me to change `tsconfig.json` from:

```
"target": "es2015"
```

to

```
"target": "es5"
```

Comment: Also consider this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58203129/4420532

Comment: did you downgrade es version for solving this issue?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I was also trying to deconstruct an object:

```
console.log('state: ', ...state)
```

But I forgot to create the object.
The solution was to deconstruct it as object:

```
console.log('state: ', {...state})
```

Answer (score 3):

Can't comment, but I'd recommend you look at the data ending up in your `headers` object. Maybe you could log the contents of `headers` just before the `return next.handle(request);` line. You could find, for example, that one of the values provided by `this.sessionParam[val][key]` is not a string and a simple `this.sessionParam[val][key] + ''` could do the trick...

Comment: This was it for me. I was assigning a header a number.  Adding toString() to it solved it

Answer (score 0):

This is not a new solution but maybe it helps someone.

I have faced this issue as well after upgrading to angular 8. It threw an error where I used Object.assign({},), it was working before.

I did not want to change all my code where I was using this in favor of the spread operator because it was way too many changes.

It worked when I  changed the target back to es5. But I was not sure this is the right move.(I'm still not sure what could be the pros of this.)

After a lot of searching I came upon this link https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#typescript-core-js-note
So here it states that for Object.assign to work, I need to have

typescript > 3.6 &
core-js >= 3

Currently angular 8 requires typescript to be less than 3.6
I am guessing this is the reason of the error, so until angular 8 supports the this typescript version or angular 9 does, I guess I will be using the same approach as Felix.

Answer (score 0):

Got same error today, my solution to this was to work with iterations on Object and then create HttpHeaders with the result.
Kinda ...

```
    let headersObj = {};

    for (var val in this.sessionParam) {
      Object.keys(this.sessionParam[val]).forEach(key => {
        headersObj[key] = this.sessionParam[val][key];
      });
    }
    request = request.clone({
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headersObj)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.fooPipe.transform(foo, ...args);

-> Error: Found non-callable @@iterator
```

This error likely means you are trying to spread an object rather than an array in ES6/ES2015.  In ES5 you could spread an object, all it would really do is spread its values.  It was convenient, but you can easily still achieve this with a library like underscore or lodash by just getting the values and then spreading them.  You can of course also just create the array yourself if you don't want to use a library.  I prefer the following way:

```
const _ = require('underscore');

return this.fooPipe.transform(foo, ..._.values(args));
```

Answer (score -2):

All Header should be in string while using angular 8+