# Using lodash is there a way to decrement i and start looping through array from the top?

Tags: loops, undefined, lodash, splice

I'm looping through an array and splicing specific elements out, but my loop breaks after the first iteration because I'm skipping over an index when one is removed. I see here [How to iterate over an array and remove elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352546/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-and-remove-elements-in-javascript) that you can use an original loop and start from the top of the array and decrement i, but can I do this same thing using lodash?

Comment: It would be much easier to answer if you'd show us your code. Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about [remove](https://lodash.com/docs#remove), [filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter) and [forEachRight](https://lodash.com/docs#forEachRight) methods. You should find the answer.

Comment: Thank you! that's exactly what I needed :) @evilive

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a for-loop, you could just remove elements with lodash's `filter` or `remove` instead:

```js
var array = [1, 10, 100, 1000];

function isLargerThan10(num) {
  return num > 10;
}

// return the filtered array:
var filtered = _.filter(array, isLargerThan10);
console.log(filtered);

// modify the array:
_.remove(array, isLargerThan10);
console.log(array);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.14.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```