# iterating a complex object, removing unwanted elements (multiple nested objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays

this seems quite an easy task, but for some reason am stuck! I tried several solutions I found in SE, mainly to recursively iterate the array/object, such as
[How to iterate over an array and remove elements in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352546/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-and-remove-elements-in-javascript) and [Looping through array and removing items, without breaking for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9882284/looping-through-array-and-removing-items-without-breaking-for-loop) (and many others) but with no luck!

I have this array

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "loc1",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "test0"
    },
    {
      "id": "sessionIgnore",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "ignore0"
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test1"
        },
        {
          "id": "sessionIgnore",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "ignore1"
        },
        {
          "condition": "AND",
          "rules": [
            {
              "id": "loc1",
              "type": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operator": "equal",
              "value": "test2"
            },
            {
              "id": "sessionIgnore",
              "type": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operator": "equal",
              "value": "ignore2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test3"
        },
        {
          "id": "sessionIgnore",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "ignore3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
}
```

and i want to remove all sessionIgnore elements

```
{
  "condition": "AND",
  "rules": [
    {
      "id": "loc1",
      "type": "string",
      "input": "text",
      "operator": "equal",
      "value": "test0"
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test1"
        },
        {
          "condition": "AND",
          "rules": [
            {
              "id": "loc1",
              "type": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operator": "equal",
              "value": "test2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "valid": true
}
```

what seems to be the problem in my case:
in both cases, I go through the array recursively

- the `delete x/array.slice()` approach:
  seems to keep the references to an empty array element, which I then have to call a cleanup method and I would prefer to avoid this
- I created an arrayRemove() function that removes the x element from the given array, but in this case, I seem to have a logic issue, and I can't parse anything after the second level of the array

any help is appreciated!

**Edit:**
in case a rules object has only a sessionIgnore element in it, I want the whole section removed
i.e. referencing the above array, if the sessionIgnore with value ignore2 was the only object in its 'rules' group, I want the whole section removed
edit2:
added the expected result

**edit in regards with nina's conversation:**

in case the object is like this:

```
{
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test1"
        },
        {
          "id": "sessionIgnore",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "ignore1"
        },
        {
          "condition": "AND",
          "rules": [
            {
              "id": "sessionIgnore",
              "type": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operator": "equal",
              "value": "ignore2"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i want this

```
{
      "condition": "AND",
      "rules": [
        {
          "id": "loc1",
          "type": "string",
          "input": "text",
          "operator": "equal",
          "value": "test1"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: That's not an array - this is an object.

Comment: do you want the same object, or a new object with changed data?

Comment: @VLAZ But the property `"rules"` is an array. I guess the OP is referring to this property, not the entire object.

Comment: @PedroCorso yes! exactly

Comment: @NinaScholz i dont mind as long as I have an array without the sessionIgnore values :D

Comment: @PedroCorso yet "I have this array" shows an object. Since this is VERY frequently confused term, I cannot be sure if OP means "I have the array in this object" or "I have this object which I call an array"

Comment: @vlaz yes i agree that might not be clear, but the end request is very clear :)

Comment: @Alexandros put your expected output in question. you are bit confused about termobject array property

Comment: @MannanBahelim added the expected result

Comment: @Alexandros yet your terminology isn't. I don't really know why you want to keep insisting in being unclear but in programming we do prefer terminology to be applied correctly. Especially considering people might come here after a google search. If somebody tries "filter array" and gets here the answers are not likely to help them out if they have plain old `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter `rules` by checking `id` an if `rules` exists, filter this property, too.

```js
function remove(o) {
    if (o.id === "sessionIgnore") return false;
    if (o.rules) o.rules = o.rules.filter(remove);
    return true;
}

var data = { condition: "AND", rules: [{ id: "loc1", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "test0" }, { id: "sessionIgnore", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "ignore0" }, { condition: "AND", rules: [{ id: "loc1", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "test1" }, { id: "sessionIgnore", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "ignore1" }, { condition: "AND", rules: [{ id: "loc1", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "test2" }, { id: "sessionIgnore", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "ignore2" }] }] }, { condition: "AND", rules: [{ id: "loc1", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "test3" }, { id: "sessionIgnore", type: "string", input: "text", operator: "equal", value: "ignore3" }] }], valid: true };

remove(data);

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: very close to the end result! and much simpler than any of my tries
 but in case of my first edit: if a rule has only a sessionIgnore element in it, i want the entire parent element removed

Comment: i don't get you which part should be removed? actually my result looks like your result ...

Comment: it does :D I didnt append another array because the question is already huge, in case the element that holds ignore2 and test2, only has ignore2, i want the whole parent element removed, instead of an element with `"condition": "AND",
          "rules": []`,
in other words, remove the element with value test2 and run your solution to that dataset :)

Comment: then you need to create a (small) data set for your use case, add it to the question along with the wanted outcome.

Comment: it makes no sense, because the first example returns nothing because every nested `id: 'sessionIgnore'` leads to a removen of the higher level. basically you can get only the result from the first example or only the one of the send example, but not both.