# How to remove all the odd indexes (eg: a[1],a[3]..) value from the array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures

I have an array like `var aa = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"];` I wanted to remove element which is place on even index. so ouput will be line `aa = ["a","c","e","g","i","k"];`

I tried in this way

```
for (var i = 0; aa.length; i = i++) {
if(i%2 == 0){
    aa.splice(i,0);
}
};
```

But it is not working.

Comment: `aa = aa.filter(function (v,i) { return !(i%2); });`

Comment: @Rajesh, no it will not..

Comment: no matter what you do, unless you shrink the array to zero length, the for loop will run forever or until there's an exception ... `aa.length` will always be "truthy"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can remove all the alternate indexes by doing this

```js
var aa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) {
  aa.splice(i + 1, 1);
}

console.log(aa);
```

---

or if you want to store in a different array you can do like this.

```js
var aa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

var x = [];
for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i = i + 2) {
  x.push(aa[i]);
}

console.log(x);
```

Comment: ya, Is it going to infinite loop for you ?

Answer (score 18):

Use **[`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** method

```js
var aa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

var res = aa.filter(function(v, i) {
  // check the index is odd
  return i % 2 == 0;
});

console.log(res);
```

---

If you want to update existing array then do it like.

```js
var aa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"],
    // variable for storing delete count
  dCount = 0,
    // store array length
  len = aa.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  // check index is odd
  if (i % 2 == 1) {
    // remove element based on actual array position 
    // with use of delete count
    aa.splice(i - dCount, 1);
    // increment delete count
    // you combine the 2 lines as `aa.splice(i - dCount++, 1);`
    dCount++;
  }
}


console.log(aa);
```

---

Another way to iterate for loop in reverse order( from last element to first ).

```js
var aa = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"];

// iterate from last element to first
for (var i = aa.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  // remove element if index is odd
  if (i % 2 == 1)
    aa.splice(i, 1);
}


console.log(aa);
```

Comment: to update existing array, just use `aa = aa.filter` instead of `var res = aa.filter`

Comment: look at the question - no reference required

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.filter()`

```
 aa =  aa.filter((value, index) => !(index%2));
```

Comment: `aa = aa. ...` as filter returns a new array, does not change the array itself

Answer (score 2):

You can use temporary variable like below.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,334,234,234,234,6545,7,567,8]

var temp = [];
for(var i = 0; i<a.length; i++)
   if(i % 2 == 1)
      temp.push(a[i]);

a = temp;
```

Answer (score 1):

in Ecmascript 6,

```
var aa = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"];
var bb = aa.filter((item,index,arr)=>(arr.splice(index,1)));
console.log(bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const aa = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"];
let bb = aa.filter((items, idx) => idx % 2 !== 0)
```

Comment: can you elaborate on your answer? it seems incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5175958/8122487) that `splice` has O(N) time complexity. **Don't use it in a loop!**

A simple alternative for removing odd indexes in place:

```js
for (let idx = 0; idx < aa.length; idx += 2)
    aa[idx >> 1] = aa[idx];
aa.length = (aa.length + 1) >> 1;
```

I use `x >> 1` as a shortcut to `Math.floor(x/2)`.