# Weird bug in Javascript splice method

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

I have an array which contains "Zeros" and I want to move all of
the "Zeros" to the last indexes of the array.

The expected output is:

```
[1,2,3,0,0,0,0]
```

But instead I get:

```
[1,2,0,3,0,0,0]
```

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0];
let count = 0;
let len = a.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 0) {
    count = count + 1;
    a.splice(i, 1);
  }
}

for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  a.push(0);
}

console.log(a);
```

Comment: The title seems to suggest you found a bug in a native JavaScript method. Suppress that thought. Convince yourself it is not that method that has the bug, but your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because splice changes the length of the array, you could iterate from the end of the array and splice the found value directly to the last index.

With this approach, you need only a single loop.

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    i = a.length;

while (i--) {
    if (a[i] === 0) {
        a.splice(a.length, 0, ...a.splice(i, 1));
    }
}

console.log(a);
```

A shorter approach without splicing - and starting from zero.

```js
var a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0],
    i, j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] !== 0) {
        [a[j], a[i]] = [a[i], a[j]]; // swap
        j++;
    }        
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 9):

When you remove the item from the array all the element shift down by one. When you advance your index (i++), you skip the shifted down item in the array which happens to be successive zero in the array.

Solution: Do the for next loop backward and it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much simpler with [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort):

```js
const array = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0];
const sortedArray = array.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a === 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (b === 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  return a - b;
});

console.log(sortedArray);
```

Comment: Why do it in O(n log n) when we can easily do it in O(n)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I thought that we also need to sort an array.

Answer (score 1):

In the for loop when you splice the array the array and it length are changed.

for that you must fix the i in the for loop by subtract 1

```
  i++;
```

and fix the length by subtract 1 or reget the length again

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0];
let count = 0;
let len = a.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 0) {
    count = count + 1;
    a.splice(i, 1);
    len = a.length;
    i--;
  }
}

for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  a.push(0);
}

console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `i--;` and `len--;` each time you use splice:

```
let a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0];
let count = 0;
let len = a.length;

for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  if (a[i] == 0) {
    count = count + 1;
    a.splice(i, 1);
    i--; len--;
  }
}

for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
  a.push(0);
}

console.log(a);
```

This is because when you splice 1 element, the keys of the array are shifted down by one, so the key of the next element you want to check is the same as the one you just removed. The len is also corrected with `len--;` because we just removed an element.

While this answer is the correct way of doing this using your original plan, it is kind of a fix. Your problem was that you loop over an array, and that array loses elements during the loop, and generally the right approach in these situations is to loop backward. This way  the elements  that risks having their key changed during the loop are the elements we already checked.

Answer (score 0):

Note that *each* call to `splice` has generally [O(n) complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5175925/whats-the-time-complexity-of-array-splice-in-google-chrome). There are many ways to instead achieve your desired result an order of magnitude more efficiently with a single O(n) iteration. Here's one:

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0]

for (let i=0, j=0; j<a.length; j++)
  if (a[j] && i != j)
    [a[i++], a[j]] = [a[j], 0]

console.log(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splicing the Array over and over again, here is a different approach:

```js
let a = [0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0];
// create some more (random) data
for (let i = a.length; i < 30; ++i)
  a[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.random() * 10);
console.log(""+a);

let i = 0, j = 0, len = a.length;
// move non-0 values to the front
while (i < len) {
  if (a[i] !== 0) {
    a[j++] = a[i];
  }
  ++i;
}
// fill the end of the list with 0
while (j < len) a[j++] = 0;

console.log(""+a);
```