# how to push into an index of an array without splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, insert, splice

splice is time complexity O(n);
I tried this version instead of splice:
which has added space complexity but i think less time complexity.

```
 let arr = [0,1];

    arr[5] = 5;
     // i need to push numbers into this index only-not to the whole array
     // push wont work on a 1d array but will work on 2d array
    arr[5] = [[], 5];
    // now it is possible to push into this index
    arr[5].push(15,125,1035);
    // remove the unnecessary empty cell []
    arr[5].shift();
    
    console.log(arr) // result [0,1,[5,15,125,1035]]
```

So is this worse than splice, or better(in terms of time complexity)?

EDIT:
this is a bad take of the answer given, my problem was i didn't understand why you couldn't push into an index of an array.
when you try:
arr = [1,2,3,4]
and then arr[1].push(2.5);
you would get an error since you try and push into a primitive(number and not an object/array).
My mistake was that i thought JS just doesn't allow it.

Comment: Why did you say that push wont work on a 1d array? `let arr = [5]; arr.push(15,125,1035)`, it gives the same `[5,15,125,1035]`.

Comment: bad example, i will give you a better array version. Edited

Comment: why do you have an empty cell at first?

Comment: read the title. try and push into a specific 1d array index. not possible in js. only with splice.

Comment: Just do `arr[5] = [5]`, then you do `arr[5].push(15,125,1035);`. By the way, what you said above (*"try and push into a specific 1d array index. not possible in js. only with splice. "*) is completely incorrect.

Comment: try and do arr[0].push(3); it will give you an error. if the arr = [0,1] for example.

Comment: Obviously it will give you an error, because you can only `push` to **arrays**, not primitives. If `arr[0]` is a number, say `5`, what do you expect that `5.push(3)` will give?

Comment: I know, that was my way of circumventing this. your way is much simpler. i wasn't aware of this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `result [5,15,125,1035]` with simply this way.

```js
 let arr = [5];
     arr.push(15,125,1035);
    
    console.log(arr)
```

Comment: I will Edit again. this is not the answer question. the result should be [0,1,[5,15,125,1035]]

Comment: oh , you forgot to put [5] in the push: arr[5].push(15,124,1035);

Answer (score 0):

Javascript leaves the underlying implementation of arrays up to the runtime, so the answer will depend on implementation used: [How are JavaScript arrays implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365975/how-are-javascript-arrays-implemented)
but I will assume this array is entirely a flat array.

Pushing to the end of an flat array is only `O(1)` if the array has space for more elements. Otherwise the array needs to be reallocated which is `O(length_of_array)`. However it should still be faster than splicing on every insertion.

If you want O(1) insertion speed then you could append to the end of a doubly linked list instead, however this is at the cost of space and lookup/iteration speed.

Answer (score -1):

the simpler answer i was looking for is by @Gerardo Furtado

```
let arr = [0,1,2,3,4,5];

    arr[5] = [5];
    arr[5].push(15,125,1035);
    
    console.log(arr) // result [0,1,[5,15,125,1035]]
```